# How to show a website under the ribbon of sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon

How do I show a C# web page developed in the asp.net VS 2013 in sharepoint online?. I have created a dropdown menu in sharepoint each menu item when clicked the  needs to go to a landing page as shown below.

something like the page viewer ?

[image]

Comment: show a C# webform means ? Please, can you explain in detail ?

Comment: I created an empty web page using VS 2013 and designed it as shown in the above image. I want it to be added below the ribbon . is it possible ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have a page (.aspx?) that you want to host on a SharePoint site? If so simply upload the page into the appropriate web app (i.e. Site Pages). Then simply navigate to the page and the page will be as displayed above (assuming that the ribbon is part of you Master Page)

Comment: simply upload the page into the appropriate web app (i.e. Site Pages)? How do you do that ?

Comment: Best thing to do is to port your solution to sharepoint. For example: your front end can be written using HTML/CSS/JS rather than using server side tags as you do in web forms. If there is any server side logic that can be exposed as REST APIs. If your front end is already written in pure HTML/CSS/JS then you can add a script editor web part to your Sharepoint home page and put your front end code in that webpart.

Comment: I almost was able to do the above with content editor webpart . only the CSS of the HTML file is messing with the Sharepoint. anyway we can make sure the css only applies to the content editor ?