# Only secure content is displayed ie 11 page viewer webpart sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am using page viewer to show website which is hosted in a different server.
regardless of which site i use i get the below error
"Only secure content is displayed" [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser specific message and it has nothing to do with SharePoint.

Since the Page Viewer is requesting an external URL browser is assuming it is some kind of cross domain calls and blocking those. You can see the actual error in browser developer console.

One fix to this problem is to add the URL into the browsers trusted sites list.

Comment: so is there a way around. I have a custom developed website with images and css that need to be shown blow the navigation. at the movement i hosted it in a server and gave the url to the page viewer. for doing something like this and what other purpose is page viewer used. I need to do something like this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183645/how-to-show-a-website-under-the-ribbon-of-sharepoint

Comment: The purpose of page viewer is to simply displaying another page inside a page. I am not aware of any other use.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are currently on a HTTPS site and want to display artifacts from HTTP site. 
Do the below:

1. Add SSL for the external site (if its IIS, then adding a cert is easy)
2. Ensure that x-frame options in your IIS site allow its contents to be displayed in external iframes.

> Note: Adding the IIS site in your IE trusted sites list will only fix it for
>   you and not for all the users. (for all users you need to push a
>   global Group Policy to add the site to their IE trusted list automatically) - [link here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84d9ca9d-4a34-4294-ac90-8bc5c47edc12/adding-trusted-sites-for-all-users?forum=ieitpropriorver) & [other one](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/188643-add-trusted-site-for-all-users-on-windows-7)